# What are the badges that Ryou wears?

Tags: code-geass, code-geass-akito-the-exiled

In *Code Geass: Akito the Exiled*, the character Ryou wears five colored badges on his outfit.

[image]

[His article on the *Code Geass* Wiki](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Ryo_Sayama) says nothing about this. What do these badges signify?

Answer (score 2):

Here are images of the badges that I believe are clearer (taken from [blogsuki.com](http://blogsuki.com/archives/2012/10/02/6009/)):[image: Ryou's badges]
[image: Ryou's badges detail]

So, what do we see?

- A rising Sun, a traditional motif for Japan;
- An 'R';
- A mask with two colored halves, smiling;
- A geometric pattern;
- A yellow-green thing that I do not even know what that is;

Apart from the rising Sun, and maybe the 'R' could stand for Ryou, I do not really have an idea of what these symbols would mean.